# LumX lx-select not updating ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I started using the LumX framework recently, and I was trying to use their Selects directive [here](http://ui.lumapps.com/directives/selects), but I'm not clear on their documentation. This is what I've got so far:

```
        <lx-select ng-model="selectedPriority" placeholder="Priority" choices="priorities">
            <lx-select-selected>
                {{ $selected.name }}
            </lx-select-selected>

            <lx-select-choices>
                {{ $choice.name }}
            </lx-select-choices>
        </lx-select>
```

And this is how I'm defining priorities (within the controller for the div containing the lx-select)

```
$scope.priorities = [
    { name: 'Urgent',               id: 1 },
    { name: 'Very important',       id: 2 },
    { name: 'Not important',        id: 3 },
    { name: 'None',                 id: 4 }
];
```

Which does give me a list to select from, but the selectedPriority model never gets updated, so that whenever I try to use that value, it's always undefined. I can't even run the example they provide in the documentation page, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So initializing the selectedPriority variable this way:

```
$scope.selects = {
    selectedPriority: undefined,
};
```

seemed to do the trick. I tried without declaring selectedPriority inside an array but as far as I could tell, this is the only way the model gets properly updated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your angular version and see if it matches your lumX version's minimum requirements.

For example a match of version 0.3.24 of lumX and version 1.2.28 of angular would produce exactly the issue you have encountered (model wouldn't update), as far as I have experimented.